# call the exec() php function in the web browser

Tags: php, sql-injection, reverse-engineering

I have a php function called getServerAddres() and I am trying to execute the exec() from the web browser. I understand this is not the proper way of using the function, I was just a task to exploit a web server using remote code injection. Any help on how to do remote code injection using the exec() through the web browser would be greatly appreciated.

Lets say the login in screen is: https://www.10.10.20.161/test/

```
function getServerAddress() {
if(isset($_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"]))
return $_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"];
else {
// Running CLI
if(stristr(PHP_OS, 'WIN')) {
    //  Rather hacky way to handle windows servers
    exec('ipconfig /all', $catch);
    foreach($catch as $line) {
    if(eregi('IP Address', $line)) {
        // Have seen exec return "multi-line" content, so another hack.
        if(count($lineCount = split(':', $line)) == 1) {
        list($t, $ip) = split(':', $line);
        $ip = trim($ip);
        } else {
        $parts = explode('IP Address', $line);
        $parts = explode('Subnet Mask', $parts[1]);
        $parts = explode(': ', $parts[0]);
        $ip = trim($parts[1]);
        }
        if(ip2long($ip > 0)) {
        echo 'IP is '.$ip."\n";
        return $ip;
        } else
        ; // to-do: Handle this failure condition.
    }
    }
} else {
    $ifconfig = shell_exec('/sbin/ifconfig eth0');
    preg_match('/addr:([\d\.]+)/', $ifconfig, $match);
    return $match[1];
}
}
```

}

The php script came from the login.php file.

Comment: Post code as such: edit your question and add the sourcecode. If you need screenshots: inline them.

Comment: Marged, I reworded my question to be more direct.

Comment: Wolverine, when you want to answer a comment or reply to someone, add the @ before the name, such as @w0lverine, and this makes the site foward a message to an user with that id, on this page...

Answer (score 1):

You dont seem to understand the exec function....

[First thing, read the documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php).

This function gets executed on the server side, and thus cannot be executed on the client side.

If what you want is the information of the host machine, then you can run the command there, and output the result.

Create this file: example.php, and enter this code:

```
<?php
   echo exec('whoami');
?>
```

Now, upload this file to the host, and make a request:

www.YOURHOST.smg/example.php

And read the result

Comment: I understand the exec() is executed on the server side, but there is a remote code execution vulnerability with the login.php script I was told to figure out what function can be executed through the web browser. The exec() would have to be that vulnerability because there is no input validation included within the function.

Comment: Just to understand how far you are into this "issue", can you issue this command from a php execution: `<?php echo('dir', $aVar); var_dump($aVar); ?>`... if so, what does it output? Edit your question, and add as much detail as you have, and a specific response you would expect